# "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source" .... Error in Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report

I'm getting this error while generationg the report
`"A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source"` .... 
I don't get for another report of mine done exactly in same way ...
Also when I render the report its running fine .....
Pls let me know if anyone knows the solution....
I'm using VS2005 for development.

Answer (score 0):

I would inspect the RDL/RDLC that makes up your report and see what's contained in the  section (usually right up at the top of the file) and confirm that the data source is configured correctly in the report.

If you are using a shared data source, make sure the shared data source is the same when you develop and deploy to a production environment. Have you logged into the Report Manager and checked the data source settings there? Try navigation to that in your browser and going to Properties > Data Sources. If the report is confused about the data source (eg. if you're developing against a different database but using the same shared data source name) you can try changing the data source to the shared one on the server.

I'm a little unsure what you mean when you say "Also when I render the report its running fine". Are you referring to the first report you created, or are you saying your (problematic) report partially renders? If it's partially rendering and then failing with a message about data sources, it sounds like one of the datasets in your report is trying to get data from a different data source. Is that possible?